# Cassandra data model approach for web analytics

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have recently started exploring Cassandra for our project. I have a doubt related to Cassandra data modelling. Lets take an example of google web analytics product. Google collects/aggregates information about the url statistics in different dimensions with different time ranges. Lets take a simple example of collecting access count of www.yahoo.com from desktop browsers vs mobile browsers for a period of 30 days (daily sum). We can model this in 2 ways -

One row key for each browser type for the same url and each day as column name with aggregate counter column type
[image: one row key for each browser]

One generic row key for url and composite key with day, url and browser type with aggregate counter column type
[image: composite column key]

Whats the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long names for column name is not a good idea as they will be stored repeatedly in each row.
You should use date,url,platform,day as primary key, and one column for count. This way if you need all days of the month you specify date,url,platform.

Comment: when you say primary key, I presume you mean the row key. Our requirement is to slice the data by date, platform, browser type etc. In future, we may also slice it by country, state, city. Basically its not a single key. So going with your model will increase the number of rows exponentially. Would that be okay? Is there any limitation on number of rows in a column family?

Comment: Below SO discussion provides little different perspective on this. Whats your thoughts on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039123/cassandra-wide-vs-skinny-rows-for-large-columns

Comment: yeap primary key or row key, we are talking different versions of cassandra;) firstly, there is not limitation in the number of rows, add more servers. For country, state, city you probably need a new table, can you explain that use case a little more? about the link, this is totally right, in your case depends on your access patterns, if you usually read only one column, it is better to have date,url,platform,day as row key, if you mostly read all 30 counters at the same time, then it would be more efficient to have date,url,platform as row key and day as column name